# Identifying the Field ID for updating an Item based on a condition in a Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, column, id

Based on a condition in a workflow I want to update an item that has been approved in the workflow.

On the conditional branch that indicates "Yes",  after I Identify the Site Address,  and the List Name, I am asked for the ID, and then the Key identifier.

I have been  using the field name as the ****Key Identifier****.   ( Not certain if that is the right) and also would like advice on how to find the **ID of a field.**

I don't see any reference to the field by an ID or number other than how the field is named.

Comment: Are you talking about Designer Workflows or Power Automate flows?

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing a window like below?
[image]

If so, the ID field is asking for the ID of the **item** you want to update, not the ID of the column. After you fill in the ID of the item, Flow will retrieve all the columns available for that Item. I am not sure how you set up the flow, if you still not sure how to set it, please share a screenshot of your flow structure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try that - this window will not allow me to share my screen shot of the flow

Comment: @ShareDeveloper Yes I see your problem. You shall not put both ID and another value inside the id field. Only Id is enough. After you fill in the ID, the action will expand and display all the columns available.